# websphere 7 is losing "spring webflows flow state" after action-state

Tags: spring, spring-webflow, websphere-7

currently we're encountering some problems with websphere 7 and spring webflow 2.3.2-RELEASE.

We want to restore some objects of a former conversation. These object have been serialized and stored somewhere. 
So if the users clicks on link in a e-mail, the former objects are deserialized and put in request.getSession() s attributes.

Then a redirect to the flow url will be processed.

In the 'on-start' section of the flow, we recognize those restored objects and put them in the conversation scope.
In this case, we want the user to be redirected to a later view-state instead of the first one.

The later view state is reached and the 'evaluate expression=".."'is processed

But after that, the flow is started again and the 'on-start' section is processed instead of showing the view-states' view.

We know, that the conversation scope gets lost. Some flags, that were set during the restoring, are false or null.

This problem does not occur on a jetty, it's a bit crazy. And we can't debug on the websphere application server. That's the quiet bigger problem...

Does anybody know this situation or have any solution?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you can't do debugging under WebSphere, perhaps you can increase the Spring Web Flow logging level or even add a custom `FlowExecutionListener` to log additional information. I agree if it's working on another JEE server, it doesn't sound like a native WebFlow behavior